# Twilio Cant make call but no errors

Tags: c#, twilio

I am trying make phonecall via Twilio using c# i am using the below code to make call.code executes successfully but i wont receive call.In my twilio page it shows staus as completed and durations.

```
        const string accountSid = "ACe200aeb6115e1f3038a012e1103bd874";
        const string authToken = "6XXXXXX";
        TwilioClient.Init(accountSid, authToken);

        var to = new PhoneNumber("+12025688652");
        var from = new PhoneNumber("+919500553163");
        var call = CallResource.Create(to,
                                       from,
                                       url: new Uri("https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/"));

        Console.WriteLine(call.Sid);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I believe that you are actually making that call successfully. You are not experiencing the call yourself because of the parameters you have used.

You are making the call from your verified number. This is your real phone number, but when you set it to be the `from` address that just means Twilio will use it as the caller ID for the call.

For the `to` address you are using your Twilio number that you have bought within your account. When you make calls to that number, Twilio makes a webhook (HTTP) request to the URL that is set as the voice response in the number's settings. Currently, that is still set to the default, so Twilio retrieves this URL: https://demo.twilio.com/welcome/voice/. If you click through, you will see that this just reads out a message.

The URL you use when you create the call is also the default URL.

So what is happening with the call is that Twilio is using your caller ID to dial your Twilio number and when the call is answered, both sides of the call are reading out that message to each other.

If you want to at least make your own phone ring, then I'd start by reversing the `to` and `from` numbers in your API call. If you do that, then you should receive a call on your phone and when you answer it you will hear the demo message. Then, once you've done that you can start writing your own [TwiML](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/) responses, possibly using [Twimlbins](https://www.twilio.com/console/runtime/twiml-bins) to get started or by building your own application.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Thank you its solved this issue.its my fault after changing from and to numbers it works fine.

Comment: Fantastic, glad to hear that is the case! If you don't mind, could you mark this answer as correct, so that if others come across it they can be confident it was the right answer too? Thanks!